# Pandas can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe, `df_pm`:

```
                             Player  GameWeek  Minutes  \
PlayerMatchesDetailID                                                 
1             Alisson         1       90   
2     Virgil van Dijk         1       90   
3        Joseph Gomez         1       90 

                             ForTeam               AgainstTeam  \
1                             Liverpool              Norwich City   
2                             Liverpool              Norwich City   
3                             Liverpool              Norwich City  

                             Goals  ShotsOnTarget  ShotsInBox  CloseShots  \
1                             0              0           0           0   
2                             1              1           1           1   
3                             0              0           0           0 
                     TotalShots  Headers  GoalAssists  ShotOnTargetCreated  \
1                             0        0            0                    0   
2                             1        1            0                    0   
3                             0        0            0                    0   
                       ShotInBoxCreated  CloseShotCreated  TotalShotCreated  \
1                             0                 0                 0   
2                             0                 0                 0   
3                             0                 0                 1  
                         HeadersCreated  
1                             0  
2                             0  
3                             0
```

this second dataframe, `df_melt`:

```
    MatchID GameWeek        Date                      Team  Home  \
0     46605        1  2019-08-09                 Liverpool  Home   
1     46605        1  2019-08-09              Norwich City  Away   
2     46606        1  2019-08-10           AFC Bournemouth  Home  

                  AgainstTeam  
0                Norwich City  
1                   Liverpool  
2            Sheffield United  
3             AFC Bournemouth  
...
575          Sheffield United  
576          Newcastle United  
577               Southampton
```

and this snippet, which uses both:

```
match_ids = []
home_away = []
dates = []

#For each row in the player matches dataframe...
for row in df_pm.itertuples():
    #Look up the match id from the team matches dataframe
    team = row.ForTeam
    againstteam = row.AgainstTeam
    gameweek = row.GameWeek
    print (team,againstteam,gameweek)

    match_id = df_melt.loc[(df_melt['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                          &(df_melt['Team']==team)
                          &(df_melt['AgainstTeam']==againstteam),
                          'MatchID'].item()

    date = df_melt.loc[(df_melt['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                          &(df_melt['Team']==team)
                          &(df_melt['AgainstTeam']==againstteam),
                          'Date'].item()

    home = df_melt.loc[(df_melt['GameWeek']==gameweek)
                          &(df_melt['Team']==team)
                          &(df_melt['AgainstTeam']==againstteam),
                          'Home'].item()

    match_ids.append(match_id)
    home_away.append(home)
    dates.append(date)
```

At first iteration, I print:

```
Liverpool
Norwich City
1
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tableau_data_generation.py", line 166, in <module>
    'MatchID'].item()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda2/envs/data_science/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 652, in item
    return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

---

printing the whole `df_melt` dataframe, I see that these four datetime values are flawed:

```
540   46875       28         TBC               Aston Villa  Home   
541   46875       28         TBC          Sheffield United  Away   
...
548   46879       28         TBC           Manchester City  Home   
549   46879       28         TBC                   Arsenal  Away
```

---

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe if your df_melt.loc don' t find any row, then the .item() method throws this error.

Comment: @JoãoVictor sim cara, I checked for that using `shape`. But where did these rows go if I print them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use *item()* on a *Series* you should actually have received:

```
FutureWarning: `item` has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version
```

Since *item()* has been deprecated in version *0.25.0*, it looks like you use
some outdated version of *Pandas* and possibly you should start from upgrading it.

Even in a newer version of *Pandas* you can use *item()*, but on a *Numpy*
array (at least now, not deprecated).
So change your code to:

```
df_melt.loc[...].values.item()
```

Another option is to use *iloc[0]*, so you can also change your code to:

```
df_melt.loc[...].iloc[0]
```

## Edit

The above solution still can raise an exception (*IndexError*) if *df_melt*
does not find any row meeting the given criteria.

To make your code resistant to such cases (and return some default value)
you can add a function getting the given attribute (*attr*, actually a
column) from the first row meeting the criteria given (*gameweek*, *team*,
and *againstteam*):

```
def getAttr(gameweek, team, againstteam, attr, default=None):
    xx = df_melt.loc[(df_melt['GameWeek'] == gameweek)
                   & (df_melt['Team'] == team)
                   & (df_melt['AgainstTeam'] == againstteam)]
    return default if xx.empty else xx.iloc[0].loc[attr]
```

Then, instead of all 3 `... = df_melt.loc[...].item()` instructions run:

```
match_id = getAttr(gameweek, team, againstteam, 'MatchID', default=-1)
date     = getAttr(gameweek, team, againstteam, 'Date')
home     = getAttr(gameweek, team, againstteam, 'Home', default='????')
```

Comment: my pandas version is `1.0.3`. `df_melt.loc[...].values.item()` throws me the same error. and `df_melt.loc[...].iloc[0]` throws me `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Comment: This means that *.loc[...]* returned nothing. Change this part to your own function, which: 1. calls *.loc[...]* and saves the result in a variable. 2. Checks whether this result is empty (*size == 0*). 3. Returns in such case some "surrogate" value.